# Appengine dev mode does not Update Changes to html file

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

When running in dev mode if I make changes to my html page the changes are not shown in the browser.  This is a GWT app and the only way I've been able to update is to recompile the gwt module.  I've tried rebuilding the project and stopping/starting dev mode without any luck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: could you send your project configuration?, are you using maven?, where is your .html?

Comment: Maybe just a browser cache issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this is just chrome caching the page.  I have disabled caching in dev tools and this fixes the issue.

Similar post found here with directions on how to disable:
[Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)